# How to plot into a histogram specific values from a file using Gnuplot

Tags: plot, conditional-statements, gnuplot, histogram

I'd like to plot two bars for a histogram, one depending on the first line of a file, while the other one depending on the second line. E.g., assuming to have a CSV file like this:

```
1 0.5
2 0.7
```

I want to plot a first bar blue of value 0.5 and a second bar red of value 0.7.

I've written the following script so far (I have a multiplot because I need to plot 4 figures of equal properties):

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set term pngcairo enhanced size 1500,700
set output 'accuracy_plot.png'
set multiplot layout 1,4
set xlabel 'rounds' font ',16'
set ylabel 'mean' font ',16'
set xrange[1:2]
set yrange[0:1]
set style fill solid
set grid xtics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#333333"
set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#333333"
set xtics font ',14'
set xtics autofreq 1
set ytics font ',14'
set key font ',12'
set title font ',20'
###
set title 'Q1'
plot "q1.csv" using 1:2 title '' with boxes linecolor rgb 'blue', \
"truth1.csv" using 1:2 title 'truth' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'black'
###
set title 'Q2'
plot "q2.csv" using 1:2 title '' with boxes linecolor rgb 'blue', \
"truth2.csv" using 1:2 title 'truth' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'black'
###
set title 'Q3'
plot "q3.csv" using 1:2 title '' with boxes linecolor rgb 'blue', \
"truth3.csv" using 1:2 title 'truth' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'black'
###
set title 'Q4'
plot "q4.csv" using 1:2 title '' with boxes linecolor rgb 'blue', \
"truth4.csv" using 1:2 title 'truth' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'black'
###
unset multiplot
```

I've tried solutions like `"<(sed -n '1,1p' q1.csv)"` but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to post all that settings for the tics, the labels and the multiplotting to show the problem.

You can use e.g. `linecolor variable` to select different line types depending on the value in the first column:

```
set terminal png enhanced
set output 'foobar.png'

set yrange [0:1]
set style fill solid

set linetype 1 lc rgb 'blue'
set linetype 2 lc rgb 'red'

plot 'q1.csv' using 1:2:1 with boxes lc variable notitle
```

[image]

Note, that the changes with `set linetype` aren't restored with `reset`, but you must restart gnuplot (version 5.0 will have a `reset session` option for this).

Answer (score 0):

I changed every CSV in this form:

```
R1 R2
0.5 0.7
```

and my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set term pngcairo enhanced size 1500,700
set output 'accuracy_plot.png'
set multiplot layout 1,4
set xlabel 'rounds' font ',16'
set ylabel 'mean' font ',16'
set xrange[1:2]
set yrange[0:1.5]
set style fill solid
set grid xtics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#333333"
set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#333333"
set xtics font ',14'
set xtics autofreq 1
set ytics font ',14'
set key font ',12'
set title font ',20'

set style data histograms
set style histogram columnstacked

###
set title 'Q1'
plot "q1.csv" using 1 lt 1 title columnhead, \
newhistogram lt 1 at 1, '' u 1 ti col, \
newhistogram lt 2 at 2, '' u 2 ti col, \
"truth1.csv" using 1:2 title 'truth' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'black'
###
set title 'Q2'
plot "q2.csv" using 1 lt 1 title columnhead, \
newhistogram lt 1 at 1, '' u 1 ti col, \
newhistogram lt 2 at 2, '' u 2 ti col, \
"truth1.csv" using 1:2 title 'truth' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'black'
###
set title 'Q3'
plot "q3.csv" using 1 lt 1 title columnhead, \
newhistogram lt 1 at 1, '' u 1 ti col, \
newhistogram lt 2 at 2, '' u 2 ti col, \
"truth1.csv" using 1:2 title 'truth' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'black'
###
set title 'Q4'
plot "q4.csv" using 1 lt 1 title columnhead, \
newhistogram lt 1 at 1, '' u 1 ti col, \
newhistogram lt 2 at 2, '' u 2 ti col, \
"truth1.csv" using 1:2 title 'truth' with lines linewidth 3 linecolor rgb 'black'
###
unset multiplot
```

This is the result (with real values):

[image]